# 'xscgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xsd

I'm using the dotnet-xscgen to create .cs files from xsd files in my project.
My project file looks like the following

```
 <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool list -g" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool install -g dotnet-xscgen --version 2.0.425" IgnoreExitCode="true" />

    <Delete Files="Generated/*.cs" />

    <exec command="xscgen -n =$(rootnamespace) xsd/Blabla.xsd" ignoreexitcode="true" />
    <move sourcefiles="$(rootnamespace).cs" destinationfiles="Blabla.cs" />
    <move sourcefiles="Blabla.cs" destinationfolder="Generated" />
  </Target>
```

Sometimes I get the error

```
[exec]   dotnet tool list -g
[exec]   Package Id           Version      Commands         
[exec]   ---------------------------------------------------
[exec]   dotnet-svcutil       2.0.1        dotnet-svcutil   
[exec]   dotnet-xscgen        2.0.267      xscgen           
[exec]   gitversion.tool      5.3.7        dotnet-gitversion
[exec]   dotnet tool install -g dotnet-xscgen --version 2.0.425
[exec]   Tool 'dotnet-xscgen' is already installed.
[exec]   The command "dotnet tool install -g dotnet-xscgen --version 2.0.425" exited with code 1.
[exec]   xscgen -n =Com.BLABLA.Definitions xsd/PlcDeregisterPackage.xsd
[exec]   'xscgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[exec]   operable program or batch file.
```

It's a bit frustrating to know why this error occurs sometimes?

Any help is highly appreciated.